# R Extract nested cumulatives from dataframe

Tags: r

given a dataframe

```
period<-c(1,1,1,3,3,3,3)
item<-c("a","b","b","a","b","c","c")
quantity<-c(1,3,2,4,5,3,7)
df<-data.frame(period,item,quantity)

df
    period item quantity
1      1    a        1
2      1    b        3
3      1    b        2
4      3    a        4
5      3    b        5
6      3    c        3
7      3    c        7
```

I want to obtain

```
period item cumulative
1       a     1
1       b     5
1       c     0
2       a     0
2       b     0
2       c     0
3       a     4
3       b     5
3       c     10
```

Not sure what is a kind of efficient way to do this in R. The file has approx 500k records and 10,000 different items
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `complete` to create the missing sequence of `period` and `item` and for each combination `sum` the `quantity` value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(period = min(period):max(period), item) %>%
  group_by(period, item) %>%
  summarise(quantity = sum(quantity, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup

# period item  quantity
#   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#1      1 a            1
#2      1 b            5
#3      1 c            0
#4      2 a            0
#5      2 b            0
#6      2 c            0
#7      3 a            4
#8      3 b            5
#9      3 c           10
```